# Routers in versions 3.4.X

Tags: django-rest-framework

Since I upgraded from version 3.3.3 to version 3.4 I'm have problems with routers:

```
File "/urls.py", line 23, in

urlpatterns = router.urls

File "~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 81, in urls
self._urls = self.get_urls()

File "~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 358, in get_urls
view = self.get_api_root_view(api_urls=urls)

TypeError: get_api_root_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'api_urls'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error.  I found I had an older version of `drf-extensions`.  I have a feeling `drf-extensions` overrides the `get_api_root_view` method, and when it's not in sync with your version of Django Rest Framework, this can cause a problem (ie. drf-extensions is passing a parameter that DRF no longer expects, but in previous versions was acceptable).

If it's not `drf-extensions` specifically, it's probably something else that's overriding `get_api_root_view` as Linovia suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have overridden `get_api_root_view` without providing the `api_url` argument since it's already part of DRF: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L292